# Xtext Grammar - switch from Terminal to Xbase

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

My current Grammar is based on the terminal grammar. Since I want to create an organize import behavior, I read something about the the XImportSection. But when I just changed the grammar and removed all the old import action from my language (and also the old import ModelElement), and added the xbase grammar parts to the mwe2 generator. Now I get an error when I want to open any file inside my editor. 
The error looks like:

```
[main] ERROR org.myDSL.ui.internal.myDSLActivator  - Failed to create injector for org.myDSL.mydslCaused by: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:521)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:125)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:95)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:34)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:39)
at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:39)
at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
... 204 more
```

This error msg causes a loop. Im not really sure what causes this error. Is there any other thing I need to look out for when switching the grammar or maybe anyone knows some good examples?

Comment: can you post the complete error message?

Comment: I edited the error msg. The error comes up in a neverending loop.

Comment: the interersting parts are still missing

Comment: There is no more. The editor wont stop and print this to console for ever, but with no more Information already given.

Comment: have a look at error log view, the console in the development eclipse

Comment: There is no stack trace in the error log. I only see the initial message : Failed to create injector for org.myDSL.mydsl

Comment: then you need to share a reprodicble project. i am sure there is somewhere the real cause for the injector problem